Convergence of Infinite series limit
I have a question regarding a particular type of series. If I have a series of positive real numbers $a_{n}$ such that the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}<\frac{1}{N}$$ holds for all natural $N>0$. By taking the limit as $N$ approaches infinity, does it follow that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=0$$
And thus all $a_{n}$ are $0$?

Yes, by the sandwich theorem for limits that first fact immediately follows. Then , the second fact follows immediately.

If you have a seres of positive real numbers such that for all $N$, $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n<\frac1N$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=3$ and all the $a_n$-s are $0$.

+1 for an original and thought-provoking question.

I think the answer is yes by the sandwich theorem, although you should change, "positive" to "non-negative" in the question.
